# Can only shinobi with Sharingan awaken Rinnegan?

Tags: naruto

I was told Nagato's eyes weren't his when he awakened Rinnegan but in fact were Madara's and were placed in Nagato (Not sure when and how mostly before his parents got killed?) but that would mean Nagato Uzumaki did not have/ awaken Rinnegan in the first place.

That leaves us with Madara Uchiha (Or his younger brother Izana Uchiha whoever awakened Rinnegan from Sharingan), then Sasuke Uchiha who awakened Rinnegan after the conversation with Sage of Six Paths, then Indra Otsutsuki who is believed to be predecessor/ancestor of Uchiha clan?

This makes me wonder if shinobi with only Sharingan (Mostly eternal Mangekyo) are able to awaken Rinnegan?

Find link below explaining why Nagato's Rinnegan isn't infact his own eyes but rather placed by Madara

[How can Obito use Rinne rebirth using Nagato's Rinnegan eyes?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/66380/how-can-obito-use-rinne-rebirth-using-nagatos-rinnegan-eyes)

Answer (score 0):

To awaken the rinnegan you have to possess both powers of the senju and the uchiha at once, so you have to possess a sharingan and gain senju cells or be a senju and transplant a sharingan or by producing a child between the two.